# Contour plot fails in R when using a defined function

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, regression

I am trying to produce a contour plot of the following function in R,

[image]

Where the values of Y_{t-1} and Y_{t-2} are between -1 and 1 and e_t just follows a normal distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation .2, i.e. e_t~N(0,.2).

I've gone ahead and set up the code to handle the function as well as calculating the value of y_t however I'm having two of the following issues.

1. When defining the `contour()` function in R I'm having issues setup up the `z` value and I get an improper output.
2. When I try to fill in the plot with colors using `filled.contour()` I get the "Error in seq.default(0, 1, length.out = ncol(z)) : argument 'length.out' must be of length 1" error and I am unsure of how to solve it.

At the end, I want to obtain a contour plot that looks like the following or similar to,

[image]

Below I've provided some sample code I've been goofing around with which only produces a simple contour plot with the function y_t not properly defined.

```
y_1<-seq(-1,1, 0.05)
y_2<-seq(-1,1, 0.05)
e_1<-rnorm(length(y_1), mean=0, sd=.2)
y_t<-0.8*y_1-0.5*y_2+(-1.6*y_1+y_2)*(1+exp(-10*y_1))^(-1)+e_1
z=outer(y_1,y_2)
Cont_test<-contour(y_1,y_2,z)
filled.contour(Cont_test)
```

Thank you for the help ahead of time.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to plot, but there are some technical issues:  you don't define `y_t` as a function, and your definition of `z` ignores `y_t`.

Comment: Thanks for the response,  it's a bit hard for me to understand as well, as I'm not really sure how to implement that y_t into the contour function in R as a function.

Comment: See @BrianMontgomery's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you want the noise in there as it confuses the contour plot.

```
set.seed(42)
y_1 <- seq(-1, 1, 0.05)
y_2 <- seq(-1, 1, 0.05)
y_t <- function(y_1, y_2) {
  0.8 * y_1 - 0.5 * y_2 + (-1.6 * y_1 + y_2) * (1 + exp(-10 * y_1)) ^ (-1) +
    rnorm(length(y_1), mean = 0, sd = .2)
}
z <- outer(y_1, y_2, y_t)
filled.contour(y_1, y_2, z)
```

[image]

Without noise:
[image]

Comment: Oh wow, this is perfect. It comes very close to what I was looking for. And yeah looking at the error term (white noise) it looks much better without it. And thank you, I see what I did wrong. I had not defined the function properly using the ```function``` term.